# What was the first piece of software to be called an engine?

Tags: history, software, terminology

Nowadays I hear a lot about graphics engines, game engines, physics engines etc.  but don't remember the term being used much, if at all, back in the 80s and the 8-bit era.
I'm not including Charles Babbage's Difference Engine or Analytical Engine, since those were hardware machines.
Where and when did this term originate?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I suspect a marketing department had more to do with it than the technicians. *How can we make it sound sexy? Hmm, maybe we can give it a steam-punk vibe.*

Comment: “Inference engine” has been in use since at least [1986](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=28337).

Comment: Note the *Analytical Engine* was supposed to be programmed - Thus at least would have contained "software".

Comment: @RichF Interestingly, hardware ads - thus, marketing - seem to be pre-dating anything software related by at least 20 years. It is apparently easy to find hardware advertisement starting from the 60ies, but I was so far unable to find any software marketing material pre-dating 1980.

Comment: I guess if you have *software engineers* it makes sense that they could write *software engines*.

Comment: The first reference of engine regarding software that I'd ever heard was regarding ID Software's Castle Wolfenstein.  I remember that the "graphics engine" was licensed to the makers of subsequent first-person three-dimensional games, like Quake, Doom, et. al.  It would have been the very early 1990's.

Comment: I can't cite evidence, but I think that "search engine" was being used around 1980, probably because there was then a fashionable idea that do search well you needed dedicated hardware designed for the purpose.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

While I don't know the first software to be referred to as an engine, it seemed useful to check Google's [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=game%20engine%2Cdatabase%20engine%2Csoftware%20engine&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgame%20engine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdatabase%20engine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoftware%20engine%3B%2Cc0):
[image: Ngram: database engine, game engine, software engine]

As can be seen, *database engine* slowly began being to be used around 1979, while *game engine* took another decade to begin catching on. Checking a few books using *software engine*, they were using the phrase generally, in titles like *Best Practices in Software Measurement* and *Practical Biometrics: From Aspiration to Implementation*.

Darn, I left out *graphics engine*. Regraphing, I see it began around 1982 and in in 2008 shows about three times the usage of *software engine*, but still well below *game engine*.

I checked links and found results for:

- 1982: *A 6809 based graphics engine* used in *Electrical Design News*
- 1983: *The inference engine is an interpreter of the facts and the rules.* used in *The Journal of Forth Application and Research - Volume 1*
- 1987: *Relational Database Engine* used in *Computer Architecture, Tutorial*
- 1995: *Wolfenstein 3-D game engine* used in *Game Developer* magazine

(Be careful if you want most recent results with the *Ngram Viewer*. By default, it cuts off at 2000, which in this case misses the recent drop-off in usage.)

Stephen Kitt pointed out that *inference engine* peaks higher than everything else, and he is right. So I'm adding a 2nd graph with both that term and *graphics engine*. The phrase *software engine* was so minor I took it out.

[image: Ngram: database engine, inference engine, game engine, graphics engine]

"Everybody" was using *inference engine* in 1990, but the drop off from that year is dramatic.  It must not have been cool any more.

Comment: Interesting... It turns out “inference engine” dwarfs all these and starts earlier.

Comment: @StephenKitt :) I hadn't heard that one in a while. It was certainly worth including though, so I added a second graph.

Comment: Its a shame to me that this data is already 9 years out-of-date.

Comment: @BrianH I'm just glad we have the data — imagine trying to figure this out nine years ago...

Comment: @StephenKitt You mean you're glad we have... a search engine? XD (I'm sorry)

Comment: In 1989 Informix renamed their C-ISAM database product to "Informix Standard **Engine**" (Informix-SE)

Comment: @krs013 I’m glad we have Google Books and search engines built on top of that, yes. Being able to quickly search through loads of books from 1950 to 2008 is fantastic, I don’t mind that we’re “missing” the last nine years of books; that doesn’t make the rest any less relevant (*especially* when we’re talking about retrocomputers).

Comment: @StephenKitt - I'd probably agree with that more readily for earlier topics. However I was a CS student in the 1980's, and a professional and gamer since then. I have an AI textbook here at my desk copyrighted in the 80's that discusses inference engines, and with some work could probably dig up the first reference to a Game Engine and Graphic Engine from the CGW's in my attic. Kind of annoying to see people using book archeology techniques to show stuff I remember happening. I'm not *that* old, damn it!

Comment: @T.E.D. I'm younger than you but I remember this stuff too, I just find it easier to find references this way than leafing through stacks of paper. Incidentally many issues of CGW are available online and can be searched too.

Comment: @T.E.D. the first use of “engine” in CGW I can find in the way we‘re interested in here is in the July 1989 issue, page 4: “They call it a CRPG with an arcade-style engine, but they insist that players won’t
want to shoot everything and there is more free-will than in most action-adventures.” The next is “chess engine” in the January 1990 issue.

Comment: The rise and fall of "inteference engine" is exactly what one would expect; it follows the [AI winter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI_winter#The_setbacks_of_the_late_1980s_and_early_1990s), that started in the late 80s (for dedicated hardware) and early 90s (for "expert systems" in general).

Comment: Google Ngram Viewer was recently updated and now works with dates up to 2019. Other terms worth including are "rendering engine", "3d engine" AKA "3D engine", and more recently "physics engine".

Comment: "simulation engine" 1974 https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9jFSAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22simulation+engine%22&q=%22simulation+engine%22 and also found some early use in VLSI simulation; "mathematical engine" goes back far earlier, though it gets hard to work out exactly when a "mathematical engine" stopped being a device and started being software, e.g. 1954 "TRIDAC is not so much a mathematical engine but a simulator" but TRIDAC was an analogue simulation computer https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bP8fAAAAMAAJ&q=%22mathematical+engine%22+  you're swamped by NASA's computer simulations of engines

Answer (score 16):

The word "*engine*", applied to game development software platforms, came into common usage in the mid-1990's and is mostly applied to that category of software today. While there is history of using "engine" to describe database and AI platforms too, it is the "**Game Engine**" that is commonly recognized by the non-technical public as a special class of commercial software, utilized by commercial game developers.

As evidence of the recent trend in using the term "engine" more in connection to game engines, and less in reference to database engines, please see the Google search trends comparing the two below. This is the trend in very recent years and months. "Game engine" is the search term represented in blue, and "Database engine" is red.

[image]

The key attribute for these game engines, or any software engine, is that they are data-driven. The game content itself is represented as data entities, not as native code. In more sophisticated systems, event actions are also created using some form of high-level, portable scripting capability. The game engine is the software that can execute this data and script. Thus, the game engine can be utilized for the creation of many different games. Depending on the flexibility of the game engine, even games of differing genres may be created; however, the game engines are commonly limited to one basic genre.

Since script execution is a common features of most game engines, there is an intersection with the concept of a **Virtual Machine**. For efficiency, game engine script is commonly "compiled" into some form of efficient byte-oriented code, or "byte code". Since the game engine runs this proprietary byte-code, the term virtual machine also makes sense when applied to these engines.

As the term "Game Engine" came into common use, it was also retroactively applied to older game platforms that met the basic requirements for the term. For example, *SCUMM*, first used in 1987 by LucasArts for Maniac Mansion, would commonly be called an early game engine today. Interestingly, the modern reverse-engineered *SCUMM* system is called "*ScummVM*", emphasizing the point of interchangeability of "VM" and "engine".

To my knowledge, the two earliest game engines, used for the production of many commercial retrocomputer games, were both developed in 1979. The "Z-Machine" was developed by Infocom and used in the creation of their many famous text-based adventure games throughout the 1980's. Also in 1979, *Automated Simulations*, which would later become *Epyx*, created a game engine for the *Dunjonquest* series of games. These games were originally released for the Commodore PET, and later ported to other retrocomputer platforms. The most famous games of this series was the *Temple of Apshai* trilogy.

Comment: I would agree the two "Engines" you mention in your last paragraph would maybe called *Game Engines* today. To my knowledge, however, neither Epyx nor Infocom were literally using that term.

Comment: I agree the term was not used until many years later, and I'm simply making the point that it is "proper" and accepted to apply the term retroactively, because its the technical attributes of the software that make it a game engine, rather than the lingo of the day. OP may feel differently, I know.

Comment: FWIW, Wikipedia list [Z-machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-machine) under Game Engines. Another early candidate would be Sierra's [Adventure Game Interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventure_Game_Interpreter) from 1984.

Answer (score 7):

The first *Game Engine* that literally used the term *Engine* was, to my knowledge, the Doom Engine by id Software in 1993.

**Database Engines**, however, used this term much earlier. dBase and, especially Foxpro, later also Borland, used the term *Database Engine* in their advertisements basically all through the 80ies.

Actually, I was trying to find Software ads and marketing material before 1980 and failed - interestingly, nobody seemed to see the need for software ads before the 1980ies. All the computer-related ads I found preceeding 1980 were advertising hardware only...

Comment: Would not the Wolf3D engine have come before Doom?

Comment: @BrianH it would have, but AFAICT people didn't talk about "games engines" before the mid-90s (as you mention in your answer), after Doom's release.

Comment: If it's any help at all, I had a quick search for information around Freescape, which via the 3d Construction Kit was technically the first licensed game engine. The kit's video refers to it exclusively as "the Freescape system". Previews of earlier Freescape games like Driller and Castle Master talk about "the amazing new 3-D technique called Freescape" and "the Freescape system" but never use 'engine'. Although hardly conclusive, I think that's evidence towards the term not being in common use up to the early '90s.

Comment: @Tommy - there were definitely licensed engines available earlier than that one.  A couple I did some work using were [3D Game Maker](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/infoseekid.cgi?id=0001956), which did generate a handful of commercial releases (e.g. [this one](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/infoseek.cgi?regexp=^Gateway+to+Hell$&pub=^Summit+Software+%5b1%5d$&loadpics=1)) and perhaps more memorably [The Quill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quill_Adventure_System) which was used in releases from several top tier publishers (e.g. Melbourne House, Firebird, Games Workshop).

Comment: Freescape may have been in many ways more impressive, but it certainly wasn't the first.  And neither of the above systems (nor others I recall, e.g. HURG, which wasn't licensed commercially AFAICT, although its publisher did offer to publish any suitably high quality games made using it) used the term "engine", so I think you must be right: somebody would have thought to call at least one of them by the name if the word was in use, I'd think.

Comment: @Jules I wouldn't strongly defend the claim — it was a recitation, not independent research — but 3D Game Maker seems explicitly not to allow redistribution of any part of itself: "Unauthorised copying, hiring, lending, exchanging, public performance and broadcasting of the software is strictly prohibited" (and lack of enforcement is not licensing). The Quill is a stronger candidate, stating merely that "Unauthorised copying, hiring or lending of the database editor or of this manual is strictly prohibited." which strongly seems to suggest that the interpreter is intended for redistribution.

Comment: @Tommy - yet, commercial publishers other than its original publisher were known to publish games written using it.  This suggests that licenses must have been available, even if they weren't included with the original release.

Comment: @Jules it suggests either that, or that the original authors just weren't that interested in pursuing the thing, which may have been cost/benefit, or may have been about philosophy. Probably the real issue here is making the test 'licensed', which invokes dry technical legalities, rather than whether it was just a game engine they wanted others to use. Also it's moot as I think your Quill example unambiguously disproved the original claim.

Comment: The "game engine" concept did not make sense in Wolf3D as it was an integrated part of the game.  You needed for somebody else to get _part_ of the game, and build a new game before you needed a name for that.

Answer (score 7):

As an addendum to tofro's anwswer, many years ago I read somewhere about when id Software would license the Wolfenstein 3D Engine (which would predate the DOOM Engine) for $50,000, which may have put them in the position of being amongst the first game developers to license out game engines. I found the passage on the Internet but it's on a web page with pirated software so I'll just paste the relevant text here (emphasis mine)

> Great enough that many companies started requesting licenses for the Wolf3D engine for their games. **This happened enough times that it became an inside joke at id and "Let's do another $50k xcopy" was John Romero's response to any new requests**.

Granted, the story is ambiguous enough that it's not clear if id Software thought of it as an "engine" yet or if they just thought it was awesome to be able to make $50k just for copying some code to a disk.

In the years since they've retronymed the DOOM engine to be "id Tech 1" (2 is Quake/Quake 2, 3 is Quake 3, 4 is DOOM 3, 5 is RAGE, 6 is DOOM 2016), but no such designation for Wolfenstein 3D. In addition, the hacking tools for Wolfenstein 3D were clunky and discouraged, whereas modding DOOM was absolutely fine with id.

So while they licensed out Wolf3D's engine they may not have called it an engine yet. Same way FPS games were called "DOOM Clones" before the other term stuck.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot comment yet to you @Tom Kidd but there is a very interesting and to me also inspiring talk about a year ago on YT titled: "Joe Rogan Experience #1342 - John Carmack" where he talks a lot of that stuff that was going on back in the day.

Answer (score 2):

The term was definitely used in conjunction with games in the 8-bit and 16-bit era, the 1980s.

For example [this item on football game 'Player Manager' from 1989](https://archive.org/details/theone-magazine-15?q=%22game%20engine%22).

"Using the same basic game engine as Kick Off" ...